# WCF Connected to Entity Framework (Cannot Attach)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I'm using Entity Framework with code-first migration, but after adding a new project to my solution for a WCF service, I get the following error when attempting to run `update-database`:

> Cannot attach the file ...App_Data\MyProject.Data.MyDbContext.mdf'
>   as database 'MyProject.Data.MyDbContext'.

**I've following projects:**

- MyProject.Data
- MyProject.WCFService

---

The currently temporary solution to this problem is to stop and remove the local db. But why do I need to this, what am I missing? It have worked before without this.

**Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio:**

```
sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0
sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
```

**In Visual Studio:**

```
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `update-database`, code first migrations will attempt to use the connection string from your current start-up project configuration file to connect to the database and perform updates.  The easiest way to resolve this in your case sounds like it would be to copy the connection string from your MyProject.Data configuration file to your MyProject.WCFService configuration file.  You can also try setting MyProject.Data to the start-up project for your solution, or you can override the parameterless constructor from DbContext in your derived DbContext class and specify an explicit location for a connection string (such as the registry).